# Ignite get operation is creating locks when same key is accessed by multiple threads

Tags: ignite

I have single ignite server node and single client. Size of data stored in some keys are huge ( approx 100MB). Get operation for one for them is taking approx 200 millis seconds for those keys. My client is multi-threaded (10 threads) and all of them is trying to access the same key, them the get time for each get operation is accumulated. I want to get rid of this lock

I have tried with normal get operation, get operations in transactions.

```
//Multi thread does the following

long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
Object result =ignite.getOrCreateCache("TestCache").get(key);
long endTimeAfterGet = System.currentTimeMillis();
if (null != result) {
System.out.println("Result Found");
}
System.out.println("Get time  = " + (endTimeAfterGet - startTime) );

//output
Result Found
Get time  = 170 ms. Time for type cast = 0
Result Found
Get time  = 178 ms. Time for type cast = 0
Result Found
Get time  = 257 ms. Time for type cast = 0
Result Found
Get time  = 288 ms. Time for type cast = 0
Result Found
Get time  = 371 ms. Time for type cast = 0
Result Found
Get time  = 420 ms. Time for type cast = 0
Result Found
Get time  = 476 ms. Time for type cast = 0
Result Found
Get time  = 537 ms. Time for type cast = 0
Result Found
Get time  = 590 ms. Time for type cast = 0
Result Found
Get time  = 655 ms. Time for type cast = 0
```

Comment: Why are your keys so big? I have a hard time believing that's the smallest unique identifier.

Comment: Hi Stephen
Thanks for replying.
The keys are not so big, the value of the data stored (in key value cache) is big.

I further investigated the issue by checking the jstack which shows locks happening at ignite side

java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:304)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.get0(GridFutureAdapter.java:178)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.get(GridFutureAdapter.java:14)......

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, you get contention on the [striped thread pool](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/thread-pools#section-striped-pool) on the server node. This thread pool is responsible for cache operations processing, and threads are chosen from it based on the partition ID. So, all operations will be sent for execution to the same thread on the server. It makes operations be accumulated in a queue.

A workaround for this contention can be using [IgniteCompute#affinityCall(...)](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/IgniteCompute.html#affinityCall-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-org.apache.ignite.lang.IgniteCallable-), that will send a job to the server node and execute it in the [public pool](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/thread-pools#section-public-pool). The trick is that local cache operations are not sent for execution to the striped pool, but the calling thread is used instead. So, threads on the server side will be chosen independently from the partition ID.

Plus you can put your processing logic into the call. It will eliminate the need to send such huge values over the network. The code will be sent to the data, and not the opposite.

The code of your affinity call can look as follows:

```java
public class CacheGetJob implements IgniteCallable<Object> {
    @IgniteInstanceResource
    private Ignite ignite;

    @Override public Object call() {
        IgniteCache<Object, Object> cache = ignite.cache(CACHE_NAME);
        if (cache == null)
            return null;
        else {
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Object value = cache.get(KEY);
            System.out.println("Get time = " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));

            return process(value);
        }
    }

    Object process(Object value) {
        // Value processing. 
    }
}
```